# In storyboard, how to push segue without button click

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I'm an iphone app developer. 
I'll use storyboard.

I want to push each other ViewController in conditions without button click.
Can I get solution? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [IOS7, Segue and storyboards - How to create without a button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205485/ios7-segue-and-storyboards-how-to-create-without-a-button)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`, if everything's already set up in interface builder. You'll need to specify the "identifier" in the Attributes inspector.

Comment: specify the identifier of what?

Comment: The identifier of the segue. Click the segue in the storyboard, then go to the attributes inspector.

Answer (score 0):

You can :

[Presenting View Controllers from Other View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)

taking the desired view controller from your storyboard with:

[instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html)