# How to show different view for logged in/not logged in

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to iOS programming, and I'm trying to do something very basic. I want the first screen in the app to be different for logged in users, and not logged in users. I am currently using the following code in my main `ViewController`:

```
if (token == nil) {
    // don't do anything
} else {
    // logged in, so show the second page
    UIViewController *loggedIn = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoggedInViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:loggedIn animated:NO];
}
```

This works, but I'm wondering if I'm following proper iOS programming conventions. Is there another, more "standard" way of doing things?

Comment: Hello, I have a demo app on this https://github.com/jasonnam/InAndOut-iOS-Demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is fine,
otherwise you could use Segues as explained here: [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/chapters/StoryboardSegue.html)

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21205550/2059307