# how to use label instead of button in prepareforsegue in swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my app you type an `integer` in a `textField` in `viewcontroller1`. If the `integer` is greater than 100 a label will pop up on screen and when you click on it, you will go to `viewcontroller2`. The same repeats from `viewcontroller2` and `viewcontroller3`.

However I want the integer in `viewcontroller1` to be displayed in another `label` in `viewcontroller3`, which I then learned to use `prepareforsegue` to be able to do so.

Now my problem is, my `prepareforsegue` only works if I use a `button`, its seems like I can't connect my label you click to go to the `viewcontroller` as a `segue` connection? (is this possible?
If not, what can I do to keep my label but work as my `button` is now, so my `prepareforsegue` is working correctly.

Comment: Do you really want to tap on a particular UI element to switch to the other view controller or is just selecting the cell sufficient?. If selecting the cell is sufficient connect the segue to the table view cell (rather than the view controller), the `sender` parameter in `prepareForSegue` is the selected `UITableViewCell` instance.

Comment: Give your segue a identifier in storyboard and, on label click or tap method use performSegueWithIdentifier("identifier", sender: self). This way the prepareForSegue gets called even on tapping label (Note: userInteraction should be enabled on label)

Comment: @harshayarabarla how would you exactly put that code into my label click:

        func handleTap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc: AnyObject! = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("nextlevelnow")
        self.presentViewController(vc as! UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: @Frederic first give the segue an identifier in storyboard later replace self.presentViewController(vc as! UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)  with self.performSegueWithIdentifier("identifier", sender: self)

Comment: How is a button anything more than a label that reacts to user interaction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOS7, Segue and storyboards - How to create without a button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205485/ios7-segue-and-storyboards-how-to-create-without-a-button)

Comment: @harshayarabarla it worked! Thanks a lot! For some reason I can't mark yours as the answer, maybe it's because nhgrif has marked my question as a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first give the segue an identifier in storyboard and on label click or tap method use `performSegueWithIdentifier("identifier", sender: self)`. This way the prepareForSegue gets called even on tapping label (Note: userInteraction should be enabled on label) 
In your code replace `self.presentViewController(vc as! UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)` with `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("identifier", sender: self)`

Answer (score 2):

A label is not a UIControl element so it doesn't recognize touch events natively. You need to attach a tapGestureRecognizer to the label (make sure user interaction is enabled on the label).  Then you can attach the gesture recognizer to your @IBAction method or trigger the segue. If using IB, the referencing outlet connection from the gesture recognizer should be tied to the label.