# Segue executing before DidSelectAtRow function

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

My situation consists of a UITable which when a row is selected it opens up a new VC and sends across a couple of variables.

My problem is that the segue is getting executed before the function DidSelectAtRow is run.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   print ("hello")
    self.selectedCellTitle = self.communities[indexPath.row]
    self.cellId = indexPath.row
    print ("now here: ", communityIds[cellId!])
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCommunitySegue", sender: self)
}
```

I know this because the `print` commands above are not being executed.  The app then crashes out when the next screen because the variables it expected to be there `(cellId)` are null.

If I delete the segue in storyboard and run then all the debug outputs in that function run correctly.  As soon as I create the segue again the app switches to the new screen and crashes before any of that above code is run.

To create my segue I am:

1) right clicking on the cell in my UITableView on VC1 within Storyboard and dragging to my VC2

2) selecting type as `show`

3) copying the segue identifier name from the `prepare for segue` function in VC 1, and pasting it into the `identifier` attribute in Storyboard for the new segue.

Any ideas?

Below is the full code for VC1:

```
import UIKit

class CommunitiesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


var selectedCellTitle: String?
var cellId: Int?
var communities = [String]() //{ didSet {     communitiesTableView.reloadData()
//     }
//  }
var communityIds = [String]()
var flag = true

var userEmailText: String?
var tempComId: Int?

@IBOutlet weak var joinCommunityButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var createCommunityButton: UIButton!


@IBOutlet weak var communitiesTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {


    self.communitiesTableView.delegate = self
    self.communitiesTableView.dataSource = self

    super.viewDidLoad()

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.communities.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.communities[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   print ("hello")
    self.selectedCellTitle = self.communities[indexPath.row]
    self.cellId = indexPath.row
    print ("now here: ", communityIds[cellId!])
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCommunitySegue", sender: self)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    if flag == true
    {

        self.communitiesTableView.reloadData()
        let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/getDetails.php?");
        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);
        request.httpMethod = "POST";
        let postString = "email=\(self.userEmailText!)";

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async
                {

                    if error != nil {
                        print("error=\(error)")
                        return
                    }

                    do{
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]

                        if let arr = json?["communities"] as? [[String:String]] {
                            self.communities = arr.flatMap { $0["name"]!}
                            self.communitiesTableView.reloadData()

                        }



                    } catch{
                        print(error)
                    }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }


}



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{


    if segue.identifier == "createCommunitySegue" {
        let createCommunityController: CreateNewCommunity = segue.destination as! CreateNewCommunity
        createCommunityController.myEmail = self.userEmailText
    }

    if segue.identifier == "joinCommunitySegue" {
        let joinCommunityController: JoinCommunity = segue.destination as! JoinCommunity
        joinCommunityController.myEmail = self.userEmailText
    }

    if segue.identifier == "showCommunitySegue" {
       let showCommunityController: ShowCommunityViewController = segue.destination as!ShowCommunityViewController
        print("yes here: ", self.cellId!)
       showCommunityController.communityIsCalled = self.selectedCellTitle
       showCommunityController.comIds = self.communityIds
        showCommunityController.communityId = self.cellId


    }
}

}
```

Comment: you should create segue from viewcontroller top and not from the cell

Comment: Create segue from ViewController to ViewController

Comment: please use following post to know how to segue and use it programatically http://stackoverflow.com/a/21205550/1142743

Comment: Excellent!! That's done it! Thanks for the link also @Vinodh

Comment: Post a answer how you acheived the solution which will be helpful for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating your segue from Cell to ViewController, you need to create segue from ViewController to ViewController like this,

[image]